# How to get TextEdit to save with a ByteOrderMark?

Tags: textedit, encoding

I've saved files with different encodings using *TextEdit.* After closing the file, with a *vim* editor, I open the file and type the following to test for the existence of a byte order mark:

> :setlocal bom?

no bom is detected for any encoding.

This script seems to directly create BOMs ok.

> #!/usr/bin/env bash
> printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > withBom.txt

But, I'd like to use a more reliable technique than that to create files with BOM. I don't understand what is going on with *TextEdit*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember right, it's not possible in TextEdit.  For BOM you need to use a more serious editor like BBEdit:

[image]